# Why is my variable not updating in the while loop?

Tags: python

may I ask what's wrong with my code as the variable is not working like it's supposed to in the while loop. It's supposed to go like player 1, 2 and 3 but it keep on repeating as player 1 instead. How can I fix it?

```py
def display_game_options(player):
    """
    Prints the game options depending on if a player's score is
    >= 14.

    Arguments:
      - player: A player dictionary object
    """
    player = {1: {'name': 'Player 1', 'score': 0, 'stayed': False, 'at_14': False, 'bust': False},
              2: {'name': 'Player 2', 'score': 0, 'stayed': False, 'at_14': False, 'bust': False},
              3: {'name': 'Player 3', 'score': 0, 'stayed': False, 'at_14': False, 'bust': False},
              4: {'name': 'Player 4', 'score': 0, 'stayed': False, 'at_14': False, 'bust': False}}

    n = 0
    playing = True

    while playing is True:
        print("--------", player[n + 1]['name'], "'s turn--------")
        print(player[n + 1]['name'], "'s score: ", player[n + 1]['score'])
        print("1. Roll")
        print("2. Stay")
        decison = input("")
        if player[n + 1]['score'] >= 14:
            print("3. Roll one")

    raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: What is `n` for?

Comment: What variable?  `n`?  Where do you update it?

Comment: which variable is not updating?

Comment: im using n for the dictionary 1,2,3,4. so each time it go through the loop, n will + 1

Comment: Just as a sidenote, `while playing is True` could be simplified to just `while playing`, since it checks if the condition is equal to `True`

Comment: for exampple in the loop, first line it will get player [0+1] name and when it go back to the same loop it will become [1+1] so it will get player 2 name instead

Comment: Also, why `raise NotImplementedError`. I don't see any `return` so your function will always stop the program once it's finished (unless enclosed by a `try`)

Comment: @MiwooNya: *"so each time it go through the loop, n will + 1"* - Why?  Where are you assigning a new value to `n`?

Comment: Why do you think `n` will change on each new loop iteration?  You never assign to it.  Do you think that every single variable in the function should be incremented inside every loop?  That makes no sense.  You can add `n += 1` if you want to explicitly increment `n`, or you can use a `for` loop, but you presumably want it to go from 4 back to 1 again.  Perhaps you want `n = n % 4 + 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It states "player 1" continuously because it uses `n` to figure that out, and `n` *never changes in your loop.*

If you want to cycle through the players, you'll *need* to modify `n` with something like (at the end of the loop, but within it):

```py
n = (n + 1) % 4 # gives 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, ...
```

For example, you can see how this works in the following transcript:

```py
>>> n = 0
>>> for _ in range(10):
...     print(n+1)
...     n = (n + 1) % 4
...
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
```

Comment: do you know hwo i can solve the issue because when i try to do n+=1 it gives me error

Comment: i tried it but it says there's unresolved reference for the second n

Comment: @MiwooNya: then you've either lost the `n = 0` line or your indentation is wrong. That `n` *definitely* exists based on the code you've shown.

Comment: could u possibly show me where to insert the equation that u mentioned?

Comment: @MiwooNya at the end of the `while` loop

Comment: alr i just got it, tysm

Comment: @MiwooNya: immediately following the "roll one" line at the same indent level as the `if`.

Comment: @paxdiablo hello, do u possibly know how i can pass dictionary as positional argument in the function()? when i just insert player in it, it says player is not defined

Comment: @MiwooNya: that's probably best in another question. However, your `player` dict is being created *inside* the function. If you want to create it outside, you should do so just before you *call* this function (and make sure the indent matches the call).